# Trigonometric equation, solutions of $x\sin x -\cos x =1$

Tags: trigonometry

Find the values of x between 0 and 360 inclusive that satisfy

$$x\sin x - \cos x = 1$$

I tried squaring it but i get

$$(x^2-1)\sin x = 2x\sin x\cos x$$

which I can't really solve.

Comment: Always be sure to use "\" for operator names such as \sin.

Comment: Hint: $x\sin x=2x\sin\frac x2\cos\frac x2=1+\cos x=2\cos^2\frac x2$ so $\cos\frac x2(x\sin \frac x2-\cos \frac x2)=0$.

Comment: Thanks, so one of the answers is cosx/2 = 0 , but how do you solve the 2nd factor?

Comment: @FengShao Does that give *all* solutions.

Comment: @SuperMage1 Don't konw much about solving the second factor...

Comment: @Allawonder Why not *all* ? The original equation is equivalent to my last form.

Comment: @FengShao I mean, how does your factorisation help to find *all* solutions?

Comment: @Allawonder Sorry I don't know how to deal with the second factor without a computer, but at least we've moved forward and got some ideas.

Comment: If $x$ is an integer, then it must be odd.

Comment: The second factor is a transcendental equation, it can't be solved exactly. You can solve it numerically with a computer. By drawing the graphs, you can see that there should be only 1 solution in the given range, around $1.3$ radians ($\approx 75^\circ$).

Comment: At least you can answer $180(+360k)$. You go home with partial credit which is better than nothing.